# How to align QLabel correctly in a QGridLayout?

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to align QLabels in a simple GridLayout but this doesn't work seems to be a bug in QT 5.9 ?

Here is my snippet, everything is in a QDialog:

```
MyDialogue::MyDialogue(QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent) {
    QLabel *labelA = new QLabel(); labelA->setFixedSize(100, 25);
    QLabel *labelB = new QLabel(); labelB->setFixedSize(100, 25);
    QLabel *labelC = new QLabel(); labelC->setFixedSize(100, 25);
    QLabel *labelD = new QLabel(); labelD->setFixedSize(100, 25);

    labelA->setStyleSheet("background-color:blue");
    labelB->setStyleSheet("background-color:yellow");
    labelC->setStyleSheet("background-color:purple");
    labelD->setStyleSheet("background-color:green");

    QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout(this);    
    layout->addWidget(labelA, 1, 1); 
    layout->addWidget(labelB, 1, 2);
    layout->addWidget(labelC, 2, 1, 2, 2);
    layout->addWidget(labelD, 3, 1, 3, 2);
}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Given that labels `C` and `D` overlap and you have given all labels the *same* fixed size your image looks exactly as I would expect.

Comment: What do you mean with "doesn't work"? The result I see is consistent with your code. What was your objective?

Comment: I don't want any overlap if possible with the last 2 rows spanning 2 columns.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the solution (my mistake) :

```
MyDialogue::MyDialogue(QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent) {
    QLabel *labelA = new QLabel();
    QLabel *labelB = new QLabel();
    QLabel *labelC = new QLabel();
    QLabel *labelD = new QLabel();

    labelA->setStyleSheet("background-color:blue");
    labelB->setStyleSheet("background-color:yellow");
    labelC->setStyleSheet("background-color:purple");
    labelD->setStyleSheet("background-color:green");

    QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout(this);    
    layout->addWidget(labelA, 1, 1); 
    layout->addWidget(labelB, 1, 2);
    layout->addWidget(labelC, 2, 1, 1, 2);
    layout->addWidget(labelD, 3, 1, 1, 2);
}
```

[image]

---

I was incorrectly thinking that for expanding a row along 2 columns (the case of labelC and labelD) I had to write the corrdinates of the starting cell (2,1) the actual position and then the ending cell (2,2). I was misguided by a Java layout manager that worked exactly that way. Just for the record here you just have to indicate the total number of row span and column span which is 2 in my case.

Comment: It may be useful to explain your mistake, instead of just posting the correct code.

Comment: OK, I was incorrectly thinking that for expanding a row along 2 columns (the case of labelC and labelD) I had to write the corrdinates of the starting cell (2,1)  the actual position and then the ending cell (2,2). I was misguided by a Java layout manager that worked exactly that way. Just for the record here you just have to indicate the total number of row span and column span which is 2 in my case (see the solution).